# Activate during Time Period

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datetime

I was wondering if there was a way for me to display a message box at a certain time during the day everyday. E.g

```
    if (DateTime >= 11:59)
    {
       messagebox.show("Good Morning");
    }
    else if (DateTime == 12:00 to 16:59)
    {
       messagebox.show("Good Afternoon");
    }
    else if (DateTime <= 17:00)
    {
       messagebox.show("Good Evening");
    }
```

If there is a way to do this please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TimeOfDay` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of a `DateTime` comparing with a `TimeSpan` values like;

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
if (dt.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(11, 59, 0))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Good Morning");
}
else if (dt.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0) && dt.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(16, 59, 0))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Good Afternoon");
}
else if (dt.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Good Evening");
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll test it and see what it comes back with.